# Optimal paralleism for a given project with gnu make

Tags: gnu-make, build-system

I'd like to know optimal number of cores needed to build a project with GNU `make`.

I can use `--max-load` to tune for an existing system, but I want to know if doubling or tripling the core count and memory would improve build wall clock times.

If I could collect statistics on how many recipes `make` holds waiting for a free core to execute and how long they occupy the core, this could be turned into a standard job scheduling problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to answer your question, really.  Maybe you can be more specific about what you'd like to know.

Obviously the more cores you have, assuming sufficient memory to support them, then the more recipes `make` can invoke in parallel without crushing your system.

If you have 2 cores and you run `make -j300` then make will dutifully invoke 300 jobs at once and your operating system will dutifully attempt to run all of them at the same time.  Most likely, your system will be swapping and context switching so much that it will make very little progress and it would take less wall clock time to run `make -j2` instead.

On the other hand, if you have 256 cores then `make -j300` is probably quite reasonable... assuming you have enough memory to ensure that all those jobs don't wait swapping memory out.

And of course, at some point (but probably far away from any reasonable number of cores you have unless you have a lot of money to spend) you will run into disk IO issues with so many compiler processes running at the same time trying to read source from the disk to compile.

Comment: It also depends on how well the Makefiles are written. I've seen Makefiles with dependencies written in such a bad way that all the work was almost sequential. Adding cores and increasing -j will not help in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

My goto number is *num cpus* + 1. This is based on a lot of informal benchmarks, and is usually very close to the optimal number. `-j9` on a hyper-threaded four core laptop, and `-j49` on my usual production build server.

The + 1 means that make keeps all the CPUs occupied, even as jobs are being retired, and is usually a teensy-weensy bit faster than without the increment.

It also means that other users can use the same multiplier without melting the machine.

Be aware though, that although `-j49` ensures there are only 49 processes actually running, the parent *make* will potentially have many more child processes than that. For instance, a single compile may mean the shell is called, which calls a shell script, which calls the compiler driver, which calls the correct compiler stage. On some toolchains my `-j49` builds have a peak of 245 child processes. A bit annoying when my ulimit *max user processes* is only 512.